# Access an attribute containing 'hyphen' in freemarker

Tags: xml, freemarker

I have an XML file which is being parsed using Freemarker. One of the attributes in a tag contains '-' and I have to define a condition based on the value of the attribute.
For a code snippet as follows:

```
<#list fields.* as field>
    <#if field.@is\-key == "false">
        HI
    </#if
```

>

Freemarker throws the following error:
FreeMarker template error:

> Left hand operand is a sequence+hash (wrapper: f.e.dom.NodeListModel).
>   Right hand operand is a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar).

The tag being parsed looks as follow:

```
<field name="*Name*" type="*Type*" is-key="true" tag="1" />
```

Please suggest how to access the attribute with a 'hyphen' in attribute name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with the hyphen itself, and actually your code works fine for me. So I guess you have a `field` element that has no `is-key` attribute. In that case, you can give a default like `field.@is\-key[0]!false`.